# Android CameraX sometimes crashes after taking images

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm implementing an attendance functionality which requires you to take current GPS location and selfie.

This is the simplified Checkin activity

```
public class CheckinActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityCheckinBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        
        binding.btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CameraActivity.launch(CheckinActivity.this, 67);
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String photoPath = CameraActivity.getResult(resultCode, data);

        if (photoPath == null) return;
        else {
           // Display the captured image on ImageView
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Camera activity which does the actual work

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PreviewView previewView;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    ActivityCameraBinding binding;
    private int mLensFacing;
    ProcessCameraProvider processCameraProvider;

    public static void launch(Activity context) {
        context.startActivityForResult(new Intent(context, CameraActivity.class), 67);
    }

    public static void launch(Activity context, int requestCode) {
        context.startActivityForResult(new Intent(context, CameraActivity.class), requestCode);
    }

    public static String getResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null) return null;
        return data.getStringExtra("IMG_PATH");
    }

    public static String getResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != 67 || resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null) return null;
        return data.getStringExtra("IMG_PATH");
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        previewView = binding.previewView;
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        mLensFacing = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA.getLensFacing();

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    processCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    bindUsecase(processCameraProvider);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));

        binding.btnCameraSwitch.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            switchCamera();
        });
    }

    private void switchCamera(){
        int newLensFacing;
        if (mLensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT){
            newLensFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK;
        } else {
            newLensFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
        }

        try {
            if (processCameraProvider.hasCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA)) {
                mLensFacing = newLensFacing;
                bindUsecase(processCameraProvider);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (CameraInfoUnavailableException ce){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera is not found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void bindUsecase(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider){

        processCameraProvider.unbindAll();

        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                .build();

        binding.btnCameraCapture.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String FILENAME_FORMAT = "ddMMyyyy_HHmmss";
            ContentValues capturedContentValues = new ContentValues();
            capturedContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    "CC_"+new SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            capturedContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/CoolCompany");
            capturedContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");


            ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions1 = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(getContentResolver(),
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    capturedContentValues).build();

            imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions1, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(CameraActivity.this),
                    new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults output) {

                            Intent data = new Intent();
                            data.putExtra("IMG_PATH", getRealPathFromURI(CameraActivity.this, output.getSavedUri()));
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                            finish();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exc) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to save image: "+exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        });

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(mLensFacing).build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(((LifecycleOwner) this), cameraSelector, imageCapture, preview);
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Context mContext, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(mContext, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Sometimes, some Samsung users (running Android 11) complain the app crashes after taking selfie. They pointed me these lines:

```
Stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed 
at android.media.Image.throwISEIfImageIsInvalid(Image.java:71)
at android.media.ImageReader$SurfaceImage.getFormat(ImageReader.java:833)
at androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageProxy.getFormat(AndroidImageProxy.java:84)
at androidx.camera.core.ForwardingImageProxy.getFormat(ForwardingImageProxy.java:71)
at androidx.camera.core.ImageUtil.ImageToJpegByteArray(ImageUtil.java:53)
at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.run(ImageSaver.java:76)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
```

Not sure if the crash is caused by some bugs inside camera library, or incorrect use of it. I use CameraX 1.2.3 because 1.3.0 and greater causes Gradle errors (perhaps conflicts with other libraries), and I want to avoid the dependency hell.

Comment: This looks like an old bug in 1.2.0. I would recommend is upgrading to 1.3.0 and try again. Please post a separate question if you run into issues with upgrading. Send me the link and I will take a look.

Comment: @Xi张熹 Sorry I provided an incorrect information. The salesperson who reported this error confirmed he was still using the older app (which used camerax 1.0.0 alpha 5). No issue so far after using the latest version (which uses 1.2.0).